# define JavaScript functions on iframe facebook app inside <fb:serverfbml> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebooker

How can I define a JavaScript function on the inside of ?  I tried to load a JavaScript file on the end tag , but I still can't call the function in the JavaScript file.

Here is the FBML tag:

```
<fb:serverfbml>
  <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml>
      <a href="#" id="this" onclick="do_colors(this); return false">Hello World!</a>
      <script src="http://absolute.path.to/your/javascript/file.js"></script>
    </fb:fbml>
  </script>
</fb:serverfbml>
```

And here is the JavaScript function in file.js:

```
function random_int(lo, hi) { 
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * (hi - lo)) + lo) 
} 

function do_colors(obj) { 
    var r = random_int(0, 255), b = random_int(0, 255), g = random_int(0, 255); 
    obj.setStyle({background: 'rgb('+[r, g, b].join(',')+')', 
                        color: 'rgb('+[r<128?r+128:r-128, g<128?g+128:g-128, b<128?b+128:b-128].join(',')+')'}); 
}
```

I use rails and facebooker to develop the application. 
Any idea or suggestion for including JavaScript functions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try loading the script first?
There are a couple of other guidelines [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Include_files).
I can see how the following could bite you if you change your script.

> Since the cache policy is set to never
>   expire, you should update the URL only
>   if the content of the script changes.
>   For example, you can change
>   http://foo.com/bar.js?v=1.0 to
>   http://foo.com/bar.js?v=2.0 or
>   http://foo.com/v1.0/bar.js to
>   http://foo.com/v2.0/bar.js when a new
>   version of the script is available.